# C# Send Image via Socket for Printing

Tags: c#, sockets

Is there a way that I can print an image without using PrintDocument? My team is insisting on printing directly to an IP without needing to install the printer on the machine (network printer, but don't want to install 40+ printers on each computer). What I have tried so far has printed out a blank page and then a single line of gibberish on my next try. Here is my latest (gibberish):

```
public static bool SendLTLReportToIP(IList<Stream> _streams, string ipAddress, int port)
        {
            bool rtn = true;

            using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                IAsyncResult results = socket.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port, null, null);
                bool success = results.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000, true);

                if (!socket.Connected)
                {
                    rtn = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var stream in _streams)
                    {
                        Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                        byte[] imageBytes = ImageToByte(image);
                        int numberOfBytes = imageBytes.Length;
                        byte[] numberOfBytesArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(numberOfBytes);
                        /*StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        string MSG = reader.ReadLine();
                        byte[] sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MSG);*/
                        int result = socket.Send(numberOfBytesArray, numberOfBytesArray.Length, 0);
                        if (result == 0)
                        {
                            rtn = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return rtn;
            }
```

The way that we were originally sending this data was using a PrintDocument with  the printpage function as below:

```
private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
            using (Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(_streams[_currentPageIndex]))
            {  
                Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pageImage.Width, pageImage.Height);
                ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, destRect);

                _currentPageIndex++;
                ev.HasMorePages = (_currentPageIndex < _streams.Count);
            }
        }
```

Is there any way that I can basically combine the two? Tried to just steal the PrintPage function and put it in my foreach, but I need an object for the DrawImage function. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would it be acceptable to install the printers in c#?
If so, please check the following [msdn article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43b594b4-81aa-478b-b705-69a56ba508d2/how-to-connect-remote-printer-in-aspnet?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: So this means that you can print a document in a printer without the drivers installed in the system? I didn't know this was possible.

Comment: Okay, good. I didn't think it was, either, but wanted to make sure. I don't know a lot about printers/printing in general. At least with this, I can come back and say why it isn't possible. Thanks!

Comment: You need to send the number of bytes before the array so the read end of conneciton know the number of bytes being sent.

Comment: Do you know if the printer supports printing image files directly? Common languages for printers to process are PCL or PostScript. The drivers normally take the printed documents and convert them to a language the printer supports before sending it to the printer. The printer port is typically 9100 (or 515 if it is using the LPD/LPR protocol - which is a little more complicated )

Comment: Thinking further, some printers may also support processing XPS documents. If it does, it may be easier to wrap the image in a XPS document instead of the PCL or Postscript thought from my previous comment.

Comment: I saw something about this, too, so I will make sure to look into it. It would be ideal if I could get this working.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes, but no.

The supported method is to use PrintDocument.

Since C# can use unsafe code and call arbitrary functions, it is of course possible to do, in C#, anything that the computer can do.

But no.

Just. No.

Don't do this. Install the printer, use PrintDocument.